# test on convergence/divergence of a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to find the convergence or divergence of $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(n^{3/2})}{n^{3/2}}}$$  and thought of this as using an identity however thats only for a limit and not a series

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your series correctly, you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n^{3/2})}{n^{3/2}}$.

Since sine is bounded between $1$ and $-1$, this series is strictly less than the series obtained if you replace the numerator with just $1$. Now you have a $p-$series. Can you take it from here?

Edit: For rigor's sake, we'll include some details. We will show that our sum is absolutely convergent. This implies convergence.

To that end, consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{\sin (n^{3/2})}{n^{3/2}}|$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin (n^{3/2})|}{n^{3/2}}$, since the denominator is strictly positive. Then by direct comparison, we see that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin (n^{3/2})|}{n^{3/2}} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$ which is known to be convergent. This shows absolute convergence, and hence convergence.

Comment: More clearly, you want to show this sum is absolutely convergent and you're upper bounding the absolute value of its terms by using the fact that $|\sin(\cdot)| \leq 1$.

Comment: Yes Alfred, that is correct series. And, I need some rigor instead of stating the coefficient of n = 3/2 so could you elaborate/complete on your work? Thanks

Comment: The comment beneath my answer supplies the rigor. I can edit the post if that's to your liking.

Comment: please do and edit with full justification